# Regression tree size in the context of state sequence analysis using TraMineR in R

Tags: r, regression, longitudinal, traminer, sequence-analysis

I am conducting a regression tree using state sequence analysis and I want the image output to have the dimensions of a Letter size paper (landscape).

When I use the code I include the regression tree appears as a separate window, always of the same size, and the actual file in my computer is empty. I have to "Save as" the window that pops in order to get the regression tree, but the size is even (width, height). I would appreciate any help:

```
st_tk <- seqtree(tk.seq ~  Gender + age_groups + race_eth + Paying_rec + Marital + 
                           Education_rec + Pop + Employment_rec + Housing + Criminal + 
                           alcohol + cocaine + cannabis + meth + benzo + diff_opioid + 
                           opioid_route + sum_comor + site,
                 data = df_seq_tree, 
                 R = 5000, 
                 diss = dist.dhd,
                 weight.permutation = "diss",
                 max.depth = 10,
                 pval = 0.05)

# Save the regression tree as a PNG image
png("Output/Takehome/Reg_tree/st_tk.png", width = 11, height = 8.5)
seqtreedisplay(st_tk, type = "d", border = NA, image.format = "png", gvpath = 'C:/Program Files/Graphviz',
               cex.main = 2)
dev.off()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I am not aware of any simple way to do it. The function `seqtreedisplay` uses `graphviz` and not the R graphic engine to produce the image. Therefore, calling `png()` does not have any effect.

in order to have more control, you need to call `dot` (the `graphviz` program) by yourself. This will allow you to change everything in the plot.

To do so, you can use the function `seqtree2dot`, which will generate the `dot` file as well as all required image.

`seqtree2dot(st_tk, filename="mytree", type = "d", border = NA, cex.main = 2)`

You can then modify the `dot` file to suit your needs. Finally, you can generate the image using `graphviz/dot`.

Comment: Thanks Matthias!! (Big fan of your work!). I managed to get every node by itself and I guess I'll arrange the regression tree myself to fit my document as the .dot file was a bit cryptic. Please keep on developing more SSA!!